# Why doesn't optical pumping work when there is no external field to cause Zeeman splitting

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, spectroscopy, cold-atoms

I discovered a strange phenomenon in an experiment related to optic pumping and magnetic resonance.

In this experiment, I optically pump electrons in Rb85 to the $5S_{1/2}, F=2, m_{F}=+2$ state and in Rb87 to the
$5S_{1/2}, F=3, m_{F}=+3$ state using light emitted by a Rb Lamp, which is conditioned to be $\sigma^{+}$ polarized.

If you have a rough picture of how optic pumping work, that is how the population is pumped into the $m_{F}=2$ state for instance, it should be obvious that this process doesn't hinge on whether there is Zeeman splitting or not.

However, if you turn the Zeeman splitting on and off by applying a square wave sweep of the magnetic field, it appears that the absorption intensity, comparing to that without Zeeman splitting, significantly drops when the magnetic field deviates from 0. So, it is certain that Zeeman splitting affects the optical pumping nontrivially. This is something novel from a theoretical perspective.

I guess there is some transition mechanism that leaks the population in $m_{F}=2$ state (again for instance) in absence of Zeeman splitting, making it impossible to maintain $m_{F}=2$ populated, or pumped. But I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: How carefully is the magnetic field zeroed in the absence of your applied field? When your applied field vanishes, if there is some residual magnetic field oriented orthogonally to your quantization axis (ie., due to Earth's magnetic field or nearby magnetic components), then it will start mixing Zeeman levels once your applied field turns off.

Comment: @HarryLevine Thanks for your comment. The comment posted by me and another member was somehow removed. It was resolved then. This phenomena is related to transition by spin-changing collisions, and such transition resonates when the initial and final state has the same energy, that is without Zeeman splitting